# Gerrit Change-ID missing in commit message

Tags: gerrit, githooks

- commit-msg hook in hooks folder downloaded correctly (calssic scp)
- `chmod +x .git/hooks/commit-msg` done
- change-id still missing in commit message

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: any idea to debug the issue is greatly welcome

Comment: Sorry, my fault :( git log -1  -> change-id is added AFTER the first commit (obviously) can't find how to delete this question..

Comment: How did you fix this issue ?